# How to save two values into a single variable fetched from a list in java

Tags: list, collections, multiple-value

```
    List<Issue> issues = issueSearcher.get().getAppropriateIssues();
```

From the above line of code I will be getting two values. 1. Project 2. count

How to save these two values in a single variable? with collections or any other concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HashMap for storing the first value 'Project' as key and second value 'count' as value. Split the value returned by your query and put to hashmap.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand:

`getAppropriateIssues()` will return a `List<Issue>`. With `Count` you probably mean the number of `Issue` in the `List`. Where does the `Project` come from?

In any way, if you want to store two variables into one, you can either

- use a `Map<K,V>` and store the two values there
- or (probably the better way) is to use a Tuple / Pair class. You can either create one yourself or use the [Apache Commons Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html).

If you want to implement a Pair class on your own it could look roughly like this:

```
public class Pair<A,B> {
    private A left;
    private B right;    

    public Pair(A left, B right) {
        // assign
    }

    // getters + setters
}
```

Comment: From the Issue object, i will get the Project. and Thanks for your Reply.

Comment: Well then it could look something like this, if you use a Pair class:
`new Pair(issues.size(), issues.get(0).getProject)` :)